# What is the way to properly set the height and width of a UIImageVIew in a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I am having trouble trying to make an image inside a TableView to not to be oversized. I drag and drop the UIImageView in the UITableViewCell and set the height and width visually (I am using Storyboards). But when I ran the app, the image looks oversized. No matter what i do (set constraints, CGRectMake among other methods), the image always looks the same).

This is my tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellID = @"cell";


TFGResultsTableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[TFGResultsTableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:cellID];
}
// Configure the cell...
cell.eventnamelabel.text = [eventnameArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
cell.userLabel.text = [userArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
cell.sportnameLabel.text = [sportnameArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

if([cell.sportnameLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Soccer"]){

    // Here I should do something to resize the image!
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
}

return cell;
}
```

These are screenshots of my current image setup:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Finally i got the solution:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
```

should be rewritten like:

```
cell.eventImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
```

Comment: Content mode is? Auto layout? Constraints? You need to give details. An image of the problem and desired version would be useful too.

Comment: What sort of details? I just have a normal UIImageView in a cell and looks oversized!

Comment: But how is that image view configured and how is its size set (and the size of the table row)

Comment: What i did is drag and drop it to the storyboard and then create the Outlet with @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *eventImage; and then do the cell.image.view in the tableview class

Comment: And how big is the image you set compared to the size of the view in the storyboard? You probably want to pin the image view size in the cell.

Comment: I added a couple of screenshots so you can see what i did and what i am getting. It makes no sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UITableViewCell` you create an IBOutlet to `eventImage`. But in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you doing like this,

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
```

Above way is wrong. you should do as below.

```
cell.eventImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
```

Comment: Its right now on Scate to Fill, but the image still looks oversized

Comment: Unfortunately i tried for modes and the image still looks the same. this doesn't make sense

Comment: I believe so....i mean all i did is to drag and drop the image view in the storyboard, connect the outlet in  the UITableViewCell and then call the cell.imageview.image.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your xib file of TFGResultsTableViewCell?

Comment: The screenshots are added !

Comment: Edit the answer. Now check